# How should I test two nested immutable js data structures for deep equality?

Tags: javascript, testing, immutability, immutable.js, jestjs

Say I have the following nested immutable data structure:

```
import { Record, List } from 'immutable'

const foo = List([
        Record({
           id: 1,
           gameState: Record({})
         })
       ])
```

How would I test that two nested immutable js data structures are equal to each other?

*test.js*

```
import jest from 'jest'
import { Record, List } from 'immutable'

describe('test', () => {
    it('that foo equals expected', () => {
        const expected = List([
              Record({
                 id: 1,
                 gameState: Record({})
               })
             ])
        expect(foo).toEqual(expected)
    })
```

Answer (score 4):

For most ImmutableJS types the test you've got would work fine.  The problem is the way you're using Records. Unlike Map, List etc the constructor`Record(...)` doesn't return a new object, it returns a constructor which can then be used to create new objects.  From the docs (https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Record):

> [Record] Creates a new Class which produces Record instances. A record is similar to a JS object, but enforce a specific set of allowed string keys, and have default values.

If you want to user Record then you can write your test like this:

```
import { Record, List, is } from 'immutable'

describe('test', () => {
    it('that foo equals expected', () => {
        const gameState = Record({});
        const gameRecord = Record({
            id: 1,
            gameState: new gameState()
        });

        const foo = List([
            new gameRecord()
        ]);

        const expected = List([
            new gameRecord()
        ]);
        expect(foo.equals(expected)).toBe(true);
    })
});
```

Compare this to using a Map instead of a Record. The test below using jest's `toEqual` function passes as expected:

```
import { Map, List, is } from 'immutable'

describe('test', () => {
    it('that foo equals expected', () => {

        const foo = List([
            Map({
                id: 1,
                gameState: Map({})
            })
        ]);

        const expected = List([
            Map({
                id: 1,
                gameState: Map({})
            })
        ])
        expect(foo).toEqual(expected);
    })
});
```

Answer (score 2):

ImmutableJS collections support `hashCode` which should give a unique identifier for different data structures and an identical one for data structures with the same contents. It works recursively in the samples I looked at.